# How to play OGG data in AudioTrack

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediacodec, ogg

I'm using the library `org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:0.8` (https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava).

I want to get the PCM data from an OGG file and use AudioTrack to play it. Using AudioTrack is a requirement for me because I will later need to concatenate multiple PCM data while it's playing to have the smoothest playback.

As you can see bellow, I tried to set up AudioTrack with data matching the file, read the file's content with the library, and write it directly into the AudioTrack, but the result is no audio when played.

I checked the loop and I'm sure the data is correctly being read.

```java
AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack.Builder()
        .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .build()
        )
        .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                .setSampleRate(44100)
                .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO)
                .build()
        )
        .setPerformanceMode(AudioTrack.PERFORMANCE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .build();

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
        this.currentSong.getTrackFile("03")
);

OggFile oggFile = new OggFile(fileInputStream);
OggPacketReader oggPacketReader = oggFile.getPacketReader();

int written = 0;
while (true) {
    OggPacket oggPacket = oggPacketReader.getNextPacket();
    if (oggPacket == null) break;
    byte[] data = oggPacket.getData();
    track.write(data, written, data.length);
    written += data.length;
}
track.play();
```

And here is some information about the file I'm trying to read:
[image: Information about the read file]

Am I even using the appropriate library for this? I recently saw something called MediaCodec to use low-level codecs, but I'm not sure where to start...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `AudioTrack` doesn't support the Vorbis format. So, you need to decode your source audio track into raw PCM before feeding it into the `AudioTrack`.

This can be done using `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec` (decoder).

Links:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#asynchronous-processing-using-buffers